# How to change the font and font size of an HTML input tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<input id="txtComputer">
```

How do I make my text inside the input tag bigger? I want to make it 24 size font. It would also be good if I can change the font from the default

Answer (score 167, accepted):

```
<input type ="text" id="txtComputer">
```

css

```
input[type="text"]
{
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: and the quicker cheating way: <input type='text' style='font-size: 16px;' value = 'Hi'  />

Comment: @ClarkSuperman Nice temptating way to achieve it quicker, but that will end you up `hard coding`, which is an inefficient practice. Unless for testing purposes.

Comment: What if you have different input types? How do set the font size universally for all input types?

Comment: @talbe009 ( css ) input { font-size: 24px; } ... note that several browsers have default settings and can be tricky to override input and form elements

Answer (score 19):

In your 'head' section, add this code:

```
<style>
input[type='text'] { font-size: 24px; }
</style>
```

Or you can only add the:

```
input[type='text'] { font-size: 24px; }
```

to a CSS file which can later be included.

You can also change the font face by using the CSS property: *font-family*

```
font-family: monospace;
```

So you can have a CSS code like this:

```
input[type='text'] { font-size: 24px; font-family: monospace; }
```

You can find further help at the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) website.

I suggest you to have a look at the CSS3 specification. With CSS3 you can also load a font from the web instead of having the limitation to use only the most common fonts or tell the user to download the font you're using.

Answer (score 6):

in your css :

```
 #txtComputer {
      font-size: 24px;
 }
```

You can style an input entirely (background, color, etc.) and even use the hover event.