# Increase size of text in an input box

Tags: html, text, input, resize

In the input box of my website the text of the page is an increased size, however, the text submitted in a textbox is a different size.

```
<input type="text" name="number">
```

How would I go about increasing the size of the text typed in to ?px?

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the font and font size of an HTML input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083430/how-to-change-the-font-and-font-size-of-an-html-input-tag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font size in a textbox in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117290/how-to-change-font-size-in-a-textbox-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

```css
 input[type="text"]{
   font-size:24px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" value="123"/>
<input type="text" name="number" value="123" style="font-size:12px"/>
```

If you wish to change the size of the font for all the inputs altogether, you can add this into your header part:

```
<style>
 input[type="text"]
 {
   font-size:24px;
 }
</style>
```

if you wish to change the font size for a specific input field, you can use:

```
<input style="font-size:25px" type="text" name="number"/>
```

in addition, if it is a number you are planning on being typed into this field you might want to use `type="number"`.  [read more about it here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/)

Comment: Thank you! This worked, when I was setting it in the CSS it was doing nothing.

Comment: @EvanWilliams I've added a code snippet so you can play with it. Maybe an other CSS command from a style sheet file is overriding yours.

Note: It is customary to upvote answers you find useful, and to accept answers on questions you posed if they have solved your answer